# Add something in front of domain name

Tags: php, web, dns, subdomain

I own a domain, suppose **www.something.com**. How can I make a web page with a link like **www.abc.something.com** ? I want to add something in front of the root domain name. Please help.

Comment: It's hard to help you basing on description above. You could create subdomain `www.abc.something.com` and set up it as alias in virtual host, or configure wildcard in your DNS and handle this on code level.

Comment: You knew to tag the question as subdomain but not use the term in your question

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the subdomain?  This is something done at the hosting level.  From there, you can do things with .htaccess and rewrites to do "other" things with it, but ultimately you have to create it at the host level.